# Make protected inner class public

Tags: c++, googletest

I have the following class:

```
class A
{
protected:
    class InnerA {};
};
```

Now I need to gain access to InnerA class in the tests. 
Theoretically I could create a test class derived from A and make some parts of A class public. I could do this with fields of course, but not with inner classes.

Is there a way to see the protected InnerA class from outside of A class hierarchy (all classes derived from A)? I would like to be able to write:

```
Test(MyTest, InnerATest)
{
    TestA::InnerA x;
    x.DoSth();
}
```

Comment: Which testing framework are you using?

Comment: I use Gtest/Gmock.

Comment: I know there are some fancy things like FRIEND_TEST or something, but I find this kind of code ugly, becasue I must change the class every time I change the test name. I would like to achieve my goal with a different method.

Comment: If it's protected it is an implementation detail, and you should not be testing implementation details.

Comment: So you say that implementation details are left untested in the project? They carry sometimes the core of business logic. How can I leave this untested?

Comment: @YotKay If you don't like FRIEND_TEST, why not change testing framework?

Comment: If it carries the code of business logic, don't make it an inner protected class!

Comment: I don't like friendliness at all. I find this kind of coding ugly.

Comment: @ juanchopanza - why do you think it is bad? I want to hide some implementation specific things, realizing some core functionality in a specific way, from the user of my class. Why do you think I shouldn't do it using inner class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* inherit and publicize the class, as a matter of fact.

```
class A
{
protected:
    class InnerA {};
};

struct expose : A {
    using A::InnerA;
};

int main() {

    expose::InnerA ia;

    return 0;
}
```

As you would any other protected member of the base. This is standard C++.

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: @YotKay - NP. And it just goes to show how "protected" those `protected` members really are :)

Comment: They are protected in a sense that you must really think what you are doing before you can use them.

Comment: @YotKay - That's one way to look at it. It also resembles Python's motto of accessibility being more a "let's be responsible adults" style. And that's okay for some applications :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expose a non-public part of `class A` for another class or function, you can try with `friend` keyword:

```
class A
{
protected:
    friend class B;
    friend void f();
    int x;
};

class B
{
public:
    void sayX()
    {
        A a;
        a.x = 12;
        std::cout << a.x << std::endl;
    }
};

void f()
{
    A a;
    a.x = 11;
    std::cout << a.x << std::endl;
}
```

If you want to expose that field to everyone, then I think we're better to put that field to public, or have get/set function for it.